# How to write working days in a month using Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Currently I am having a little bit of a trouble. I am trying to create a template, that will automatically write out all working daysl in a selected month (month and a year will be in cell A1 and B1)
Could somebody give me an advice? I was trying playing around with some functions, but I have to state that I don't have any idea how to achieve this

Comment: is vba an option? only purely by excel formulas? try `=WORKDAY(DATE(B1,A1,0), 1)`

Comment: You may be interested in NETWORKDAYS, NETWORKDAYS.INTL, WORKDAY, WORKDAY.INTL - but your question is at least ambiguous about what exactly you need. You want the **number** of days? You want the **list** of working days? Something else?

Comment: Please show some sample data with expected result, and briefly explain your attempt to solve the question.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, I would use the WORKDAY function, along with an index column, so that we can work through all the days in the month:

```
=IF(MONTH(WORKDAY(DATE($C$1,MONTH(DATEVALUE($B$1&" 1")),0),$A2,$F$2:$F$4))<>MONTH(DATEVALUE($B$1&" 1")),
    "",
    WORKDAY(DATE($C$1,MONTH(DATEVALUE($B$1&" 1")),0),$A2,$F$2:$F$4)
)
```

This looks complicated but is fairly simple when you break it into chunks. Here is an image which may help:

[image]

Lets start with this part of the formula:

```
MONTH(DATEVALUE($B$1&" 1"))
```

All this does, is convert the name of the month to the number of the month.

```
WORKDAY(DATE($C$1,MONTH(DATEVALUE($B$1&" 1")),0),$A2,$F$2:$F$4)
```

This is the part of the formula which does most of the work. It creates a date from the supplied month/year, adds the appropriate number of working days depending on the current row (index column) and taking into account the list of bank holidays).

```
IF(MONTH(WORKDAY(DATE($C$1,MONTH(DATEVALUE($B$1&" 1")),0),$A2,$F$2:$F$4))<>MONTH(DATEVALUE($B$1&" 1")),
    "",
```

This part looks very complicated but it is actually just a copy of the above formula, and compares it to the supplied month. If it is different (meaning we have passed the end of the month that we are interested in) it causes a blank to be returned instead of a date.